# how to speed up tex4ht image generation process?

Tags: tex4ht, svg

Currently, I tell tex4ht to use svg instead of png for math images. This results in better image quality. However, it is slow in image generation, as it takes about 1-2 seconds for each image to be generated since it has to load the idv file each time to make each image for each math expression.

Is there a way to speed this process up? I'll describe the current process I use for reference.

I edited  `sudo vi /usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex4ht/base/unix/tex4ht.env` and add these 2 lines

```
G.svg
Gdvisvgm -n -p %%2 -c 1.2,1.2 -s %%1 > %%3
```

as shown in this image

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Next, edited my tex4ht cfg file (called nma.cfg) and added svg entry

```
 \Preamble{ext=htm,charset="utf-8",p-width,pic-align}
  \Configure{Picture}{.svg}  
  \makeatletter
  \Configure{graphics*}
  {svg}
  {
    {\Configure{Needs}{File: \Gin@base.svg}\Needs{}}
    \Picture[\csname a:GraphicsAlt\endcsname]{\csname Gin@base\endcsname.svg
            \csname a:Gin-dim\endcsname}
  }
  \begin{document}
  \EndPreamble
```

Next, I call tex4ht on the latex file as follows

```
  make4ht -u foo.tex "nma,htm,pic-align,notoc*"
```

where `make4ht` is found in https://github.com/michal-h21/make4ht

If you do not have `make4ht` installed, then the command

```
  htlatex foo.tex "nma,htm,pic-align,charset=utf-8,notoc*" " -cunihtf -utf8"
```

will work as well. Here is foo.tex with 2 equations which will cause 2 images to be generated

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} %must be included
\begin{document}    
\[
  x = \sin(y)
\]
and
\[
  x2 = \sin(y)
\]    
\end{document}
```

Now we see tex4ht loading the idv each time for each image:

```
......
t4ht.c (2012-07-25-19:28 kpathsea)
t4ht -f/foo.tex 
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex4ht/base/unix/tex4ht.env)

Entering foo.lg
System call: dvisvgm -n -p 1 -c 1.2,1.2 -s foo.idv > fo0x.svg
processing page 1
  page size: 58.1681pt x 13.0909pt (20.4437mm x 4.60093mm)
  page written to <stdout>
1 of 2 pages converted in 0.244021 seconds
System return: 0

System call: dvisvgm -n -p 2 -c 1.2,1.2 -s foo.idv > fo1x.svg
processing page 2
  page size: 64.7136pt x 13.0909pt (22.7442mm x 4.60093mm)
  page written to <stdout>
1 of 2 pages converted in 0.243742 seconds
System return: 0
```

Is there a way to speed this up to avoid loading the idv each time for each equation and do them all at once?  Currently it takes 4 days to build my large latex file and I need a way to speed this up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each generated picture is placed on it's own page in special `dvi` file, with extension `idv`. By default, `tex4ht` calls converting commands on each page separately, which normally isn't problem, unless you have lot of pages as in your case. In this case, it may be faster to convert all pages in the `idv` file with one command. The catch is that we can't name the output files in the way we need, so we have to rename them after conversion.

If you call `dvisvgm` to convert all pages:

dvisvgm -n -p 1- filename.idv

files will be named like `filename-01.svg`, but we need them to be named like `filename0x.svg`

This is possible to fix using `make4ht` build file:

```lua
Make:add("dvisvgm","dvisvgm -n -TS1.25,1.25 -c 1.2,1.2 -p 1- ${input}.idv")

local max_count = 5
local image_format = "${input}-${zeroes}${page}.${ext}"
local oneimage_format = "${input}.${ext}"


local function file_exists(fn)
  local f = io.open(fn,"r")
  if f ==  nil then return false else f:close() return true end
end



local function locate_file(par,ext, count)
  local count = count or 0
  par.ext = ext
  local zeroes = string.rep("0",count)
  par.zeroes = zeroes
  if count > max_count then 
        local one = oneimage_format % par
        if file_exists(one) then
            return one
        else
          return false, "max_count exceeded" 
        end
    end
  local fn = image_format % par
  if file_exists(fn) then 
    return fn
  else 
    return locate_file(par, ext, count+1)
  end
end

Make:htlatex{}
Make:htlatex{}
Make:htlatex{}
Make:tex4ht{}
Make:t4ht{}

Make:dvisvgm{}
Make:image("svg$",function(arg)
   arg.input = arg.source:gsub(".idv$","")
   local fn,msg = locate_file(arg, "svg")  
   if not fn then
     print("Image processing error: "..msg)
   else
     arg.filename = fn
     local cmd = "mv ${filename} ${output}" % arg
     print(cmd)
     os.execute(cmd)
   end
 end
)
```

we should disseminate this file little bit:

```lua
Make:add("dvisvgm","dvisvgm -n -c 1.2,1.2 -p 1- ${input}.idv")
```

this register new command, `dvisvgm`, which will extract all svg files from the `idv` file. `${input}` is special instruction which is replaced with a input file name.

```lua
Make:htlatex{}
Make:tex4ht{}
Make:t4ht{}
Make:dvisvgm{}
```

this is the build sequence, LaTeX is called only once, you may want to add more `Make:htlatex` calls if you use toc or references. The idv file is created after `tex4ht` run, so we need to call `Make:tex4ht{}` and `Make:t4ht{}` explicitly and after that to `Make:dvisvgm{}`.

```lua
Make:image("svg$",function(arg)
   arg.input = arg.source:gsub(".idv$","")
   local fn,msg = locate_file(arg, "svg")  
   if not fn then
     print("Image processing error: "..msg)
   else
     arg.filename = fn
     local cmd = "mv ${filename} ${output}" % arg
     print(cmd)
     os.execute(cmd)
   end
 end
)
```

this function is called for each image. `arg` is table with image properties, which is the `idv` file name, page number and the output file. to construct the file, we need to get the basename with deleting the `.idv` suffix from `arg.source`. we try to find the svg file filename with `locate_file` function, when we found it, it is moved to the correct location, which is in the `arg.output` variable.

```lua
local function locate_file(par,ext, count)
  local count = count or 0
  par.ext = ext
  local zeroes = string.rep("0",count)
  par.zeroes = zeroes
  if count > max_count then 
        local one = oneimage_format % par
        if file_exists(one) then
            return one
        else
          return false, "max_count exceeded" 
        end
    end
  local fn = image_format % par
  if file_exists(fn) then 
    return fn
  else 
    return locate_file(par, ext, count+1)
  end
end
```

because we don't know the exact file name produced by `dvisvgm` we need to locate it. the situation is worsened with the fact that `dvisvgm` may add leading zeroes before the page number, so we need to try several possibilities when we can't find the file on the first attempt.

Save the make file as `foo.mk4`. From the command line output:

```
Make4ht: dvisvgm -n -c 1.2,1.2 -p 1- foo.idv
processing page 1
  page size: 58.1681pt x 13.0909pt (20.4437mm x 4.60093mm)
  page written to foo-01.svg
processing page 2
  page size: 64.7136pt x 13.0909pt (22.7442mm x 4.60093mm)
  page written to foo-02.svg
2 of 2 pages converted in 0.193865 seconds
```

and:

```
mv foo-01.svg foo0x.svg
mv foo-02.svg foo1x.svg
```

and the result:

[image]

Comment: Why do we need -TS and also -c? It seems that -TS and -c are equivalent, as claimed in the manpage, and I don't know why the scaling is necessary (it seems to me that some of the formulae exceed the page because of this).

Comment: @FrankScience I don't remember, I guess that this was a mistake. The -c option should suffice. You can also choose a different value. Note that this answer is almost four years old and bit obsolete. It is best to use the `dvisvgm_hashes` extension for a fast generation of the SVG files. See the `make4ht` documentation for details.

Comment: So I only need to call tex4ebook with option dvisvgm_hashes, and modify the .mk4 file, leaving only compilation (htlatex, tex4ht, t4ht) right?

Comment: @FrankScience something like `tex4ebook -f epub+dvisvgm_hashes filename.tex`. You don't need `Make:image` in the build file then. You may still need to require the `SVG` format using `\Configure{Picture}{.svg}` in the `.cfg` file or using the `svg` option on the command line

Comment: Is the following braces including `\Configure{Needs}` and `\Picture` still necessary in [your answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/235472/15172)? By the way, maybe it would be a bit beneficial to update that answer.

Comment: @FrankScience no, SVG is supported by default in `tex4ht` for some time

Comment: I tried `tex4ebook epub+dvisvgm_hashes`, and I end up with something like `...texmf-dist/scripts/make4ht/extensions/dvisvgm_hashes.lua:251: attempt to concatenate field 't4ht_par' (a nil value)` What's wrong with that?

Comment: I tried to modify the code and found that dvisvgm_hashes converts images to a hashed name but tex4ebook claims the needed ...x.svg not found.

Comment: I inserted the code `if v.params.t4ht_par == nil then v.params.t4ht_par = "" end` after line 249 in the extension (I don't know the syntax of lua. I guess it from my knowledge of other programming languages).The "not found" error seems harmless: it's shown at `Copy: cp "test100x.svg" "test-epub/OEBPS". It seems that you need to remove these cp's in the code of tex4ebook.

Comment: I also found that in the generated epub file, the output of epubcheck will claim a lot of svg file not found.

Comment: Now I see, that's because in the OEBPS/content.opf, there are a lot of `<item id='test###x.svg' ... />` etc. I will post a topic here.