# TeX4ht aliasing on equations' images

Tags: compiling, tex4ht, html, htlatex, aliasing

I am compiling a `.tex` file to html using `TeX4ht` induced by the `htlatex` command.

When `TeX4ht` compiles a document and turns equations into images, however, it produces low-quality images with little to no anti-aliasing on the text, which looks pretty ugly! It also does a funny thing where it makes scaled brackets too big.

Desired:

[image]

Undesired:

[image]

Is there any way to solve this problem using TeX4ht? I know there are [websites which produce the desired images](http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php) (such as the top example above).

Comment: using images for the math is evil, you can configure tex4ht to use mathjax

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I considered that but I am using it to export LaTeX documents to my blog (http://physicsandchemistryrevision.tumblr.com/). Tumblr's dashboard unfortunately does not support MathJax.

Comment: can't you just link to mathjax cdn? http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/11904/adding-mathjax-to-tumblr

Comment: you can use svg for images, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/228943/2891 but I would also prefer mathml with mathjax

Comment: also see http://12000.org/my_notes/faq/LATEX/layout/